# Converting a function to vb from csharp

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-conversion

I converted this code using the converter.telerik.com

**From**

```
public Decimal CartTotal()
{
   return this.Items.Sum<CartItem>((Func<CartItem, Decimal>) (x => x.Total));
}
```

**To**

```
Public Function CartTotal() As Decimal
   Return Me.Items.Sum(Of CartItem)(CType((Function(x) x.Total), Func(Of CartItem, Decimal)))
End Function
```

but the compiler says

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Sum' accepts this
>   number of type arguments.

Comment: Where is the `Where`?

Comment: I meant `sum`, it has been corrected

Comment: I don't really understand why that C# isn't just `return this.Items.Sum(ci => ci.Total);`, in which case the VB would be `Return Me.Items.Sum(Function(ci) ci.Total)`.

Comment: The C# code should be just `this.Items.Sum(x => x.Total);`. Nothing else is needed. No explicit type, no `Func<>` syntax. It looks like someone converted *VB.NET* code to *C#* using a converter tool

Comment: @Smith when I tried to convert your code using the [converter.telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/), it throws error `Specified method is not supported.` take a look at the @PanagiotisKanavos comment

Comment: thats because i omitted `()` after the `CartTotal`

Comment: @Smith instead of trying to convert code using tools, just write correct code and use the assembly where this was found *without* conversions. You *don't* need to convert code in .NET, you can use a C# class library in a VB.NET project just fine. Besides the *vast* majority of .NET developers work with C#, and it's not because MS told us to. If you want to maintain the C# code, maintain the C# code. Don't try to "convert" it to something else without understanding what it does

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos “the vast majority of .NET developers work with C#, and it's not because MS told us to” — It actually is. Initial .NET development strongly focused on C# and allocated way fewer resources to VB.NET, both for internal development and for marketing. VB was supported solely to make VB6 people switch. This was a conscious decision at the time (I was told this personally by a person involved in the .NET marketing at the time).

Comment: @KonradRudolph actually not at all. It was the *exact opposite*. I was around then and it wasn't that MS told us. We didn't want to use VB.NET at all, even those of us with mutli-year experience in VB6 and certifications. Only MS insisted on promoting VB.NET equally

Comment: @KonradRudolph those of us at the time, that worked with VB6 but knew about Java, C++ etc jumped ship as fast as we could. At last, we had a platform that allowed us to create UIs easily and a *good object-oriented language*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I mean … I was *also* around at the time, since the pre-beta community preview, and it was *exactly* like that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph different countries, different subsidiaries, different *local* marketing departments. Different *programmer* bakcgrounds - if you cared about object oriented programming why use VB.NET? Different *languages* too - C# was the new langauge, not VB.NET. Which talks did you attend at Teched? The ones about the new language, C#, or the ones about the not-quite-same-as -the-old-VB6?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos VB.NET and C# have *exactly the same* OOP capabilities. VB.NET just traditionally lacked behind in terms of ease-of-use features, precisely because its development was neglected compared to C#’s (which I completely support, by the way; having two redundant languages is nonsense). There are lots of reasons to choose C# over VB but OOP capabilities isn’t one of them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's what the subsidiary said back then. There *were* differences but he **huge** difference was the environment - the shops that insisted on VB6 and then VB.NET were those focused on churning "enterprisey" code, not good engineering or moving forward. *Microsoft marketing* (the local one of course) said that "VB devs are cheaper than Java devs".

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos See, I 100% agree with your last comment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what if i want to do a `Sum` with `Where`?

Comment: @Smith check [Introduction to LINQ in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq). In the query form just add a `where` clause before the `select`. In the method form, add a `Where()` before the `Sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to drop the generic specifier on 'Sum':

```
Public Function CartTotal() As Decimal
   Return Me.Items.Sum(CType(Function(x) x.Total, Func(Of CartItem, Decimal)))
End Function
```

Exactly why VB has a problem with this escapes me at the moment, but it's a common problem.  In general, the issue affects usage of any of the IEnumerable extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a question about what it *should* be, or one about Telerik's converter?  If the latter, then you'd probably want to take it up with Telerik...

If the former, then maybe

```
Return (from item as CartItem in items Select item.Total).Sum()
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Qj3My)

Comment: The query isn't needed. You can pass a lambda to `Sum` tath returns the `Total`